# Checking user role on login using CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.2

I want to create an admin panel for my site, for this I've created `admin.ctp`. In DB table name user contain column `role`, where role=admin/regular(user).

There is only one login form, and the question is, Is it possible to place a 'check' that if `user.role=admin` then redirect to the `admin/user/dashboard` and if `user.role=regular` then `layout=default`? my AppController.php contains:

```
function beforeFilter(){
    $this->Auth->allow('index','view','login','home');
    $this->set('admin',$this->_isAdmin());

    $this->set('logged_in',$this->Auth->loggedIn());
    $this->set('current_user',$this->Auth->User());
    if ((isset($this->params['prefix']) && ($this->params['prefix'] == 'admin'))) {
        $this->layout = 'admin';
    }
```

And usersController.php

```
function beforeFilter(){
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow('*');
    if($this->action=='add' || $this->action=='edit'){
        $this->Auth->authenticate=$this->User;
    }
}

function login(){
    if(!($this->Auth->loggedIn())){
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            if ($this->Auth->login()) {
                if($user['role'] === 'admin'){
                    $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect('admin',array('controller' => 'user','action' => 'admin_dashboard')));
                }
                $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect(array('controller' => 'posts','action' => 'index')));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Your username/password combination was incorrect.',
                    'alert',array(
                        'plugin' => 'TwitterBootstrap',
                        'class' => 'alert-error'
                    ));
                $this->set('forget', 'Forgot Your Password');

            }
        }
    }else
    {
        $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect(array('controller' => 'posts','action' => 'index')));
    }
}
```

using cakephp 2.2.3.
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would do it (remember to change `field('name')` accordingly with your group model).

```
if ($this->Auth->login())
{
    this->User->Group->id = $this->Auth->user('group_id');
    switch ($this->User->Group->field('name'))
    {
        case 'admin':
            $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect('admin',array('controller' => 'user','action' => 'admin_dashboard')));
            break;
        case 'regular':
            $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect(array('controller' => 'posts','action' => 'index')));
            break;
        default:
            //...
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In AppController set:

```
$this->Auth->authorize = array('Controller');
```

And then do the following

```
public function isAuthorized($user = null)
{
    if (isset($this->request->params['admin']))
    {
        if(!isAdmin)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

CakePHP actually already provides a useful Authentication and Authorization framework that's trivial to enable.

Here's how to authorize based on a role stored in the database, from [the CakePHP manual](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html#authorization-who-s-allowed-to-access-what). I also included an example `beforeFilter()` that changes the login redirect action if the user is an admin:

### AppController.php:

```
public $components = array(
  'Auth' => array(
    'authorize' => array('Controller'),
    'loginRedirect' => array('/'),
));

public function beforeFilter() {
  // This allows us to use $user in all controllers.
  $this->set('user', $this->Auth->user());

  // If the user is an admin, override the loginRedirect
  if ('admin' === $this->Auth->user('role')) {
    $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array(
      'controller' => 'users',
      'action' => 'admin_dashboard',
    ));
  }
}
```

### UsersController.php:

```
public function isAuthorized($user) {
  // Ensure the user has a valid role. If not, deny access to all actions:
  if ((!isset($user['role'])) || ('' === $user['role'])) return false;

  // If we're trying to access the admin view, verify permission:
  if ('admin_dashboard' === $this->action)
  {
    if ('admin' === $user['role']) return true;  // User is admin, allow
    return false;                                // User isn't admin, deny
  }

  return true;
}
```

There are many ways you can arrange the authorization, so adjust the `if/else` statements to best suit your needs. The `isAuthorized()` method is relatively simple, you just need to return `true` if you want to allow access, or `false` if you don't.

Comment: thanks for your reply. there is an extra opening bracket '(' in your first 'if'. what I want to do is, when user login `code`if($user['role'] === 'admin') then redirect to siteurl/admin/user/dashboard. but I am unable to get this result,and now any regular user can access this admin/user/dashboard by putting manual url.

Comment: @yoggi, please let me know that what is the problem with my UsersController, is there any logic problem? like in login() 

if($user['role'] === 'admin'){                        $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect('admin',array('controller' => 'user','action' => 'admin_dashboard')));
                    }
this should be redirect?

Comment: @user1984675: See my edit. You can use the AppController's `beforeFilter()` to change the `loginRedirect` action on-the-fly.

Comment: this isn't working redirect me to the same location, please checkout the following lines of `routes.php` which I have tried seperately:
`Router::connect('/admin/*', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'admin_dashboard'));`
or
`Router::connect('/admin/:controller/:action/*', array('admin' => true, 'prefix' => 'admin', 'controller' => 'user', 'action' => 'admin_dashboard'));`
or
`Router::connect('/admin', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index', 'admin' => true));`

Answer (score 1):

I actually want to post some code to perhaps shed light on this subject for myself as well.
I have achieved a simple dashboard for each user that extends the /Users/view - my next step is trying to get User-specific access to each set of data

AppController

```
class AppController extends Controller {
    public $components = array(
        'Acl',
        'Auth' => array(
            'authorize' => array(
                'Actions' => array('actionPath' => 'controllers')
            )
        ),
        'Session'
    );
    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Session');

    public function beforeFilter() {
        //Configure AuthComponent

        $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');
        $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');
        $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'dashboard');
        $this->Auth->allow('display');
    }
}
```

UsersController

```
public function dashboard() {
    $id = $this->Auth->user('id');
    $this->set('user', $this->User->read(null, $id));

    $group_name = $this->User->Group->field('name', array('id' => $this->Auth->User('group_id')));
    $this->redirect = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'dashboard');
}
```

dashboard.ctp

```
$this->extend('/Users/view');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php public function dashboard() {
    $id = $this->Auth->user('id');
    $this->set('user', $this->User->read(null, $id));

    $group_name = $this->User->Group->field(
        'name', array('id' => $this->Auth->User('group_id'))
    );
    $this->redirect = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'dashboard');
}   
?>
```